# whats the best way to compress a date?

Tags: java, mysql, compression

my site needs to store the ip and timestamp of every visit on mysql. i am concerned that very quickly i will have 1e6 rows in my database.

what is the best way to compress a date on mysql or java? does mysql already compress dates? ideally, I would like to un-compress the date values rather quickly to generate reports.

Update: sorry i meant a mil per day. but I guess that is still minuscule.

Comment: The size of date is the least of your storage problems with that amount of records per day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mate, one million rows is a *tiny* database. I wouldn't be worrying too much about that. In any case, MySQL uses a pretty compressed format (3 bytes) anyway as per [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html):

```
DATE: A three-byte integer packed as DD + MM×32 + YYYY×16×32
```

In other words, at bit level (based on the `1000-01-01 thru 9999-12-31` range):

```
00000yyy yyyyyyym mmmddddd
```

Comment: 1 million row = 3MB approx (data fragmentation, etc.)

Comment: @Yanick - add an extra 4 byte value for each IP address.  But yea, this is a miniscule amount of storage by today's standards.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in MySQL datetime type. A million rows isn't that many.

Answer (score 1):

A mysql timestamp would be only 4 bytes. An integer representing the timestamp would be the same. It would be efficient to save it as a mysql type since you'd be able to index and/or query based on that column efficiently.

Any "compressed" form not a mysql type would be inefficient to query.